# Смена значения Accept-language с UserDefaults | Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, afnetworking

Есть приложение по денежным переводам. На главном, в зависимости от выбранного языка по ключу из UserDefaults, который отправляется в Header’e, бэкэнд возвращает инструкцию к переводам на том или ином языке.

Проблема такая: при смена языка в методе viewWillAppear вызывается функция fetchTransferAdvice(), но почему-то в Header’e язык не обновляется, хотя локализация работает.

Как при повторных запросах отправлять обновленный Accept-Language?

Note: при rebuilde с xcode, то язык меняется в header'e меняется.